# Rewrite rule for pretty URL: redirecting 'index.php?parameter' to 'slug/index.html'

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects, url

My original URL is:

```
    http://example.com/video_in.php?video_id=1
```

and I want my link to be:

```
   http://example.com/shaandaar/kinna_sona.html
```

`shaandaar` and `kinna_sona` are the slugs in my database.

This is my .htaccess file

```
  AddDefaultCharset utf-8
  Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
  RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]

 RewriteRule ^artist/(css|js|images)/(.*)?$/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^artists/([^/]*)\.html$ artist_search.php?&letter=$1 [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^albums/([^/]*)\.html$ album_search.php?&letter=$1 [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^artist/([^/]*)\.html$ artist_in.php?artist_id=$1 [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^album/([^/]*)\.html$ album_in.php?&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ song_in.php?album_id=$1&song_id=$2   [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ video_in.php?album_id=$1&video_id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

all the links are working  axceppt video_in.php

```
    What should I write in my *.htaccess* file?
```

Comment: What have you tried? How do you think this might work? If the _video-id_ is required for the real (ugly) URL, but isn't present in the "pretty" URL, where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: you can see here what i have tried till now

Answer (score 4):

> and I want my link to be: `http://example.com/shaandaar/kinna_sona.html`
>
> shaandaar and kinna_sona are the slugs in my database. What should I write in my .htaccess file?

This is the best way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /video_in.php?firstslug=$1&secondslug=$2 [L]
```

In the RewriteRule, the `^` starts the matching. This: `([^/]+)` is broken down as follows:

`[^/]` means match anything except the `/`. Its a good way to not confuse the rewrite engine.

The plus means match one or more. So `[^/]+` means match any number of characters as long as there is no `/`.

Then I put the whole thing in brackets so I can use it later. The first set of brackets is #1, and the second set is #2.

then I added a backslash in front of the dot because its a way of specifying a dot as a literal character to match.

Then of course the `html` to match that as well.

To end the matching, I use the `$`.

When the match is found, `/video_in.php?firstslug=(first captured value)&secondslug=(second captured value)` will load in the background while the friendly URL stays in the web browser.

In your case and if you use your URL, the values are then shaandaar and kinna_sona respectively. then you can use your script to read the values.

If you want to go paranoid style, you can use this script to make sure your values are processed correctly:

```
<?php
  print_r($_GET);
  exit();
?>
```

When the script runs, you should see an array with your name and value pairs, one per line.

Comment: HEY....I am not able to redirect properly i have put my code in .htaccess file please see that and help me out. all links are working but this is not the last one.video_in.php is not working

Comment: You might want to try starting over on a blank .htaccess file because you might have some other apache directives in that file (or even in the main config file) that are processing your test URLs instead of the one I showed.

Comment: can we have more than one .htaccess in one site

Comment: yes if parts of your site are in different folders other than document root folder. But its not a bad idea to make a folder, put .htaccess in it and play around with it.

Comment: my .htaccess file is in root folder what shall i do??

Comment: rename the old .htaccess file, then copy my first two lines of code and put it into a new .htaccess file and upload it to the document root folder. then test a bunch of urls to see if they work correctly.

Comment: thanks dude....can u please tell me if i want example.com/contactus.php to be example.com/love-to-hear-from-you.html. what shall i do for these problem

Answer (score 0):

> `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ song_in.php?album_id=$1&song_id=$2   [QSA,L]`
>   `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ video_in.php?album_id=$1&video_id=$2 [QSA,L]`

You have a conflict with the last two directives. You are using the same *pattern* for both, so all these requests are going to `song_in.php`. The second (`video_in.php`) directive is never going to be processed.

Assuming `/shaandaar/kinna_sona.html` (for example) could refer to either a song or a video then you are going to have to differentiate between songs and videos in the URL.

Comment: thanks dude....can u please tell me if i want example.com/contactus.php to be example.com/love-to-hear-from-you.html. what shall i do for these problem

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I follow. If you are suggesting that the URL for your contact page should be `love-to-hear-from-you` instead of `contactus` - I would stick with `contactus`. (?!)

Comment: please dude tell me is it possible or not

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. Are you asking whether the URL `/love-to-hear-from-you.html` could load the file (ie. internally rewrite to) `/contactus.php`?

Comment: thank you brother actually i succeeded in that. thank you so much.....yes I want these just display in address bar.any ways thank you